# An application of covariate shift

Tags: sampling, covariate-shift

I am reading about an application of covariate shift: draw $(\textbf{X},y)\in\mathbb{R}^p\times\mathbb{R}$ from distribution $P$ with generative model $p(\textbf{x},y)=p(y\mid\textbf{x})p(\textbf{x})$. The problem wants to estimate $\beta_P^*=\text{argmin}_{\beta}P(y-\textbf{X}^\top\beta)^2=\text{argmin}_{\beta}\int(y-\textbf{x}^\top\beta)^2p(\textbf{x},y)d\textbf{x}dy$. However, the i.i.d. data $(\tilde{\textbf{X}},\tilde{y})$ comes from another distribution $Q$ with generative model $q(\textbf{x},y)=p(y\mid\textbf{x})q(\textbf{x})$. The conditional distributions are the same but the marginal distributions are different.

Define $\beta_Q^*=\text{argmin}_{\beta}Q(y-\textbf{X}^\top\beta)^2$. It is straightforward to see that $\beta_P^*=\text{argmin}_\beta Q\left\{\frac{p(\textbf{X})}{q(\textbf{X})}(y-\textbf{X}^\top\beta)^2\right\}$ is another form of the estimator of interest. I have the following questions:

1. What are the generative models ($p(\textbf{x},y)$ and $q(\textbf{x},y)$) for $P$ and $Q$ where $\beta_Q^*\neq\beta_P^*$?
2. If $p$ and $q$ are known, can we find an estimator $\hat{\beta_P}$ of $\beta_P^*$ that draws data from $Q$? Is this estimator consistent and asymptotically normal?
3. If $p$ and $q$ are unknown, and we only have covariates $\textbf{X}_j$ drawn from $P$, what is the estimator $\hat{\beta_P}$ of $\beta_P^*$ in this case?

Thank you.

Comment: Does this paper help? Understanding Failures in Out-of-Distribution Detection with
Deep Generative Models https://arxiv.org/pdf/2107.06908.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Define probability density functions $p(x)\sim N(0,I_n)$ and $q(x)\sim N(0,2I_n)$. Define the conditional probability density functions
   $$p(y|x) = q(y|x) \sim \text{Bernoulli}\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)+\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i^3-\frac{1}{2}.$$
   Define generative models P, Q as
   $$p(x,y) = p(x)p(y|x),~~~~q(x,y) = q(x)q(y|x).$$
   We compute the least square solution
   $$\beta^*_P = (PXX^{\top})^{-1}PX^{\top}Y,~~~~\beta^*_Q = (QXX^{\top})^{-1}QX^{\top}Y.$$
   Note that $PXX^{\top} = I_n$, $QXX^{\top} = 2I_n$ and
   $$PX^{\top}Y = \int x^{\top}(\int yp(y|x)dy)p(x)dx = \int x^{\top}\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i^3p(x)dx =
   \begin{bmatrix}
   \int x_1^4p(x)dx  \\
   \int x_2^4p(x)dx \\
   \vdots \\
   \int x_n^4p(x)dx
   \end{bmatrix} = 3*\textbf{1}_n$$

$$QX^{\top}Y = \int x^{\top}(\int yq(y|x)dy)q(x)dx = \int x^{\top}\sum_{i = 1}^{n} x_i^3q(x)dx =
\begin{bmatrix}
\int x_1^4q(x)dx  \\
\int x_2^4q(x)dx \\
\vdots \\
\int x_n^4q(x)dx
\end{bmatrix} = 12*\textbf{1}_n$$
(we use the result that for any Gaussian r.v. $x\sim N(0,1)$, we have $~\mathbb{E}(x^4) = 3$.)

Therefore, we can compute the least square solution
$$\beta^*_P = 3*\textbf{1}_n,~~~~\beta^*_Q = 6*\textbf{1}_n.$$

2. Define the estimator
   $$\hat{\beta}_n=\left(Q_n\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}XX^\top\right)^{-1}\left(Q_n\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}X^\top Y\right),$$
   we will show that this $\hat{\beta}_n$ is consistent to $\beta^*_P$ and $\sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta}_n-\beta_P^*)$ is asymptotically normal.

To prove consistency, we show that $\hat{\beta}_n\to\beta^*_P$ a.s. as $n\to\infty$. Note that
$$\hat{\beta}_n-\beta^*_P=\left(Q_n\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}XX^\top\right)^{-1}Q_n\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}X(Y-X^\top\beta^*_P),$$
and $\beta^*_P$ satisfies the population normal equation $Q\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}\left(Y-X^\top\beta^*_P\right)X=0$, therefore, we have
$$\hat{\beta}_n-\beta^*_P=(Q_n\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}XX^\top)^{-1}(Q_n-Q)\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}X(Y-X^\top\beta^*_P).$$
Since $Q\|\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}XX^\top\|_1<\infty$ (finite moment condition), by SLLN, we have
$$Q_n\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}XX^\top\to Q\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}XX^\top = PXX^\top~~~~ a.s.,$$
By CLT, we have
$$\sqrt{n}(Q_n-Q)\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}X(Y-X^\top\beta^*_P)\stackrel{d}\longrightarrow N(0,Q\frac{p(X)^2}{q(X)^2}(Y-X^\top\beta^*_P)^2XX^{\top})$$
By Slutsky's theorem,
$$
\begin{aligned}
&\sqrt{n}(Q_n\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}XX^\top)^{-1}(Q_n-Q)\frac{p(X)}{q(X)}X(Y-X^\top\beta^*_P)\stackrel{d}\longrightarrow \\
& (PXX^\top)^{-1}N(0,Q\frac{p(X)^2}{q(X)^2}(Y-X^\top\beta^*_P)^2XX^{\top}).
\end{aligned}
$$
Therefore, by the property of linear transformation for normal distribution
$$\sqrt{n}(\hat{\beta}_n-\beta_P^*)\stackrel{d}\longrightarrow N(0,(PXX^\top)^{-1}Q\frac{p(X)^2}{q(X)^2}(Y-X^\top\beta^*_P)^2XX^{\top}(PXX^\top)^{-1}).$$

The asymptotic property further indicates that
$$\hat{\beta}_n-\beta_P^*\stackrel{d}\longrightarrow \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}N(0,(PXX^\top)^{-1}Q\frac{p(X)^2}{q(X)^2}(Y-X^\top\beta^*_P)^2XX^{\top}(PXX^\top)^{-1}),$$
as a result, when $n\rightarrow\infty$,
$$\hat{\beta}_n-\beta_P^*\stackrel{p}\longrightarrow 0.$$
by the fact that convergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability to the same constant.

3. In this setting, we use the data drawn from $Q$ and samples $\{X_j\}_{j = 1}^M$ to estimate $\beta^*_P$. To impose the estimator in 1(c), we have to approximate the unknown density functions $p(x)$ and $q(x)$. Take $p(x)$ as an example, we make a parametric assumption on it and use kernel methods to estimate this density function. First choose a Mercer kernel $K(\cdot,\cdot)$ on the covariate space $R^p$, such as the Gaussian kernel. By Riesz representation theorem, kernel $K$ induces a unique RKHS $\mathcal{H}$ on $R^p$.
   ***Assumption:*** Suppose the density function $p(x)$ is in a kernel exponential family, i.e.
   $$p\in\{p_f(x) = e^{f(x)-A(f)}q_0(x),f\in\mathcal{H}\}$$
   we find the optimal function by solving the following optimization problem:
   $$f^* = \mathop{\arg\min}\limits_{f\in\mathcal{H}}\hat{J}(p_f)+\lambda\lVert f\rVert_{\mathcal{H}}^2,$$
   where $J$ is a bilinear functional of $p_f$ derived by kernel $K$ and Fisher divergence.

After we get the approximation $\hat{p}$ and $\hat{q}$, we impose the estimator
$$\beta_P^* = \mathop{\arg\min}\limits_{\beta}Q_n\frac{\hat{p}(X)}{\hat{q}(X)}(Y-X^{\top}\beta)^2.$$